# how to prompt duplicate values in column of a table while executing update statement?

Tags: jsp

I need to update a query on comparing two values in two diff tables, if there is a match then update and also prompt me if there is any duplicate values in both the tables...

here is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" align="right">
document.write("<p>" + Date() + "</p>");
</script>
</head>
    <BODY bgcolor="#99CCFF">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

<br>

        <%
       // ResultSet resultset;
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String user = "hr";
        String pass = "hr";
        String value1 = request.getParameter("value1");
        String value2 = request.getParameter("value2");
        String value3 = request.getParameter("value3");
        String value4 = request.getParameter("value4");



        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, pass);


         pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("update Table1 set value1 ='"+ value1+"',value2='"+value2+"',value3 = '"+value3+"',value4 = '"+value4+"' where SerialNo in(select DB.SerialNo from Table1 DB, Table2 OUT where OUT.SerialNo = DB.SerialNo and DB.Transaction_Status = 'IN')");
         pstatement.executeUpdate();


           %>
            <br><br>
    <TABLE align="center" style="background-color: #efefef;"WIDTH="30%" border="1">
        <tr><th>Order Issued, Database Updated Successfully</th></tr>
    </TABLE>
       <br><br>
           <%
             pstatement.close();
             }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
  out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch(SQLException e){
  out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  out.println("AnyException: " +e.getMessage());
  }
  finally {
  // Always close the database connection.
  try {
  if (connection != null) connection.close();
  }
  catch (SQLException ignored){
  out.println(ignored);
  }
  }


        %>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This code is working fine, It is updating if there is match, Now I need to prompt if there is any duplicate values in tables, The Program should prompt me if there a duplicates values....Please can anyone help me how to do this???

Thanks in advance,
Sailaja.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can catch the DuplicateKeyException after the end of the try block

catch(DuplicateKeyException)
{
--Your code here to display for duplicate key entry
}

Happy coding :)

Comment: DuplicateKeyException is an ejb specific class